# How to extract dictionary from array of dictionary that has specific value for key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have the following array:

```
myArrey = (
    object1:{key1:valueA, key2:valueB},
    object2:{key1:valueC, key2:valueD}
)
```

What do I need to do to find an object that his value for key1 is keyC?

```
MyObject obj = [myArrey abrakadabra with: key1 and:valueC];
NSLog(@"obj - %@",obj);

obj = object2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`

```
NSInteger indexOfMatchingDictionary = [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [[obj valueForKey:@"key1"] isEqual:@"valueC"];
}
NSDictionary *matchingDictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexOfMatchingDictionary];
```